# Extract values from column of csv file using pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

I am trying to extract rows from two csv files based on values of two columns. My data is in `df22` and `df33`, and both have different number of records. The name of columns in both files are same but values are different. I want to match the `‘Education_Period’` column in `df22` with same column in `df33` to find the students records (rows) based on exactly same education period and closest `‘Program_startDate’`, for closest `‘Program_startDate’` needs to compare the start date in `df22` with same column in `df33`. If there are more than one rows with equal closest `‘Program_startDate’` values , then just choose one at random (It means at the end, If there are more than one records with similar `‘Education_Period’` and closest `‘Program_startDate’` then choose one at random).

I have written some python code which is matching only the `‘Education_Period’` columns but I need to add the other condition for `‘Program_startDate’` as well to get the final output. Secondly, the above code requires a fix. if we run, the output contains one pair of 77.2 because it removes the duplicates. The program should not remove another 77.2 because there is its matching present in `df33` to work out further. I will be thankful if anybody could tell that how to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df22 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student_IDs': {0: '23C', 1: '34B', 2: '11X', 3: '88N',4:'22A'},
    'Education_Period': {0: 100.5, 1: 77.2, 2: 77.2, 3: 99.9,4:77.2},
    'Waiting_Period': {0: 5.5, 1: 3.0, 2: 8.5, 3: 12.0, 4:12.0},
    'Program_startDate': {0: '29/03/2018', 1: '12/12/2009', 2: '14/09/2019', 3: 
     '20/03/2017', 4:'30/03/2015'},
})

df33 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student_IDs': {0: '11X', 1: '99Y', 2: '88Z',3: '12Z',4: '234M',5: '34M'},
    'Education_Period': {0: 30.5, 1: 77.2, 2: 14.1,3:77.2,4: 100.5, 5:100.5},
    'Waiting_Period': {0: 40.0, 1: 20.0, 2: 19.1, 3: 15.0, 4:19.2, 5: 44.5},
    'Program_startDate': {0: '29/03/2018', 1: '12/12/2009', 2: '14/09/2016', 3: 
     '26/06/2018', 4:'30/03/2015', 5: '30/04/2018'},})

df22['Program_startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df22['Program_startDate'], dayfirst=True)
df33['Program_startDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df33['Program_startDate'], dayfirst=True)

Condition1 = np.intersect1d(df22['Education_Period'], df33['Education_Period'])
df22 = df22.set_index('Education_Period')
df33 = df33.set_index('Education_Period')
df44 = df22.loc[Condition1].reset_index().drop_duplicates('Education_Period')
df55 = df33.loc[Condition1].reset_index().drop_duplicates('Education_Period')

df44.to_csv('file2.csv')
df55.to_csv('file3.csv')
```

---

```
Input:

df2
Student_IDs Education_Period  Waiting_Period     Program_startDate   
   
23C                     100.5            5.5            29/03/2018
34B                     77.2             3.0            12/12/2009
11X                     77.2            8.5             14/09/2019
88N                     99.9            12.0            20/03/2017
22A                     77.2            12.0            30/03/2015

df3
Student_IDs Education_Period  Waiting_Period     Program_startDate   
  
11X                     30.5             40.0         29/03/2018     
99Y                     77.2             20.0        12/12/2009
88Z                     14.1             19.1        14/09/2016
12Z                     77.2             15.0        26/06/2018
234M                    100.5            19.2        30/03/2015
34M                     100.5            44.5        30/04/2018



Output:

df4
Student_IDs Education_Period  Waiting_Period     Program_startDate   
   
23C              100.5           5.5                     29/03/2018
34B              77.2            3.0                     12/12/2009
11X              77.2            8.5                     14/09/2019

df5
Student_IDs Education_Period  Waiting_Period     Program_startDate 
234M             100.5           19.2                    30/04/2018
99Y              77.2            20.0                    12/12/2009
12Z              77.2            15.0                    26/06/2018
```

Please note that we have made match based on same 'Education_Period' and around the closest 'Program_startDate'. In case if there are more than one records with same matching 'Education_Period' and 'Program_startDate' then just select one at random.

Comment: your description is kind of confusing, can you provide data that you expect to be on output?

Comment: @Ruli I have added the required output. If you still need any clarification then please let me know.  I am new to python and stuck in this code. I will be very thankful if you or someone else please help me out. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I correctly understand your question, but if you want to drop duplicates based off off not one, but more columns, you need to pass their names as a list into the arguments of `.drop_duplicates()` method:

```
df44 = df22.loc[Condition1].reset_index().drop_duplicates(['Education_Period', 'Program_startDate'])
df55 = df33.loc[Condition1].reset_index().drop_duplicates(['Education_Period', 'Program_startDate'])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply as I wrote I need matching records based on same 'Education_Period' and the closest 'Program_startDate' by using these columns from df22 and df33. In case if there are more than one records with same matching 'Education_Period' and 'Program_startDate' then just select one at random.

Comment: Thank you @Oskar_U . In your code there were few missing/wrong parenthesis but I fixed in my code. To see what this code returns I tried to run but I am getting error where dates are subtracted : 

File "C:/Users/44697147/ClinicalTrials_Study/Updated_Analysis_December.py", line 370, in match_pairs

df23['TD'] = (df23['Start Date_x'] - df23['Start Date_y']).abs()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 692, in <lambda>
lambda x: op(x, rvalues))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

How about using `.merge()`, to create intermediate dataframe that contains all matching results of two dfs in order to determine time deltas `TD` of "Program_startDate" of pairs of the same "Education_Period":

```
df23 = df22.merge(df33, on='Education_Period', how='inner')
df23['TD'] = (df23['Program_startDate_x']-df23['Program_startDate_y']).abs()
df23 = df23.sort_values(by=['TD']).reset_index()
```

then you could select indices of those rows which have top 2 minimal values in `TD` for each subset respectively:

```
df23i = df23.sort_values(by=['TD']).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Education_Period', 'Student_IDs_x']).groupby(['Education_Period'])['TD'].nsmallest(2).index
df23i = [x[1] if type(x) == tuple else x for x in df23i]

df23j = df23.sort_values(by=['TD']).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Education_Period', 'Student_IDs_y']).groupby(['Education_Period'])['TD'].nsmallest(2).index
df23j = [x[1] if type(x) == tuple else x for x in df23j]
```

and slice intermediate table to get separate dfs:

```
df44 = df23.loc[df23i, ['Education_Period','Student_IDs_x', 'Waiting_Period_x', 'Program_startDate_x']].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'Student_IDs_x':'Student_IDs', 'Waiting_Period_x':'Waiting_Period', 'Program_startDate_x':'Program_startDate'}).drop_duplicates(subset=['Education_Period', 'Student_IDs']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Education_Period', 'Student_IDs'])
df55 = df23.loc[df23j, ['Education_Period','Student_IDs_y', 'Waiting_Period_y', 'Program_startDate_y']].reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'Student_IDs_y':'Student_IDs', 'Waiting_Period_y':'Waiting_Period', 'Program_startDate_y':'Program_startDate'}).drop_duplicates(subset=['Education_Period', 'Student_IDs']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Education_Period', 'Student_IDs'])
```

Comment: Thank you @Oskar_U . In your code there were few missing/wrong parenthesis but I fixed in my code. To see what this code returns I tried to run but I am getting error where dates are subtracted : File "C:/Users/44697147/ClinicalTrials_Study/Updated_Analysis_December.py", line 370, in match_pairs df23['TD'] = (df23['Start Date_x'] - df23['Start Date_y']).abs() File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 692, in <lambda> lambda x: op(x, rvalues)) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Yep, make sure you perform all necessary data types conversions before applying calculations and logic and ensure you pick right strategy of error handling when converting columns with dates as string to actual datetime objects, ie. `pd.to_datetime`  "errors" argument

Comment: I have resolved that issue, but now I am getting this error on the below line. I am still trying to run your code. Any idea how to resolve that? I googled the error but I am confused as I did not understand. df23i = df23.sort_values(by=['TD']).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Total_Trial_Duration', 'NCT Number_x']).groupby(['Total_Trial_Duration'['TD'].nsmallest(2).index])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: You've got a typo. Make sure parentheses are correctly closed like so: df23i = df23.sort_values(by=['TD']).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['Total_Trial_Duration', 'NCT Number_x']).groupby(['Total_Trial_Duration'])['TD'].nsmallest(2).index

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for bothering you again. I have run the code and I am not getting the required output. Here I cannot attach the image to show you the output so please see the output at this link https://ibb.co/6WGVt7P. In fact, there should be only one entry in df55 with 100.5 because for 100.5 in df44 there is one matching with closest  Program_startDate in df55. Also, there is another issue with code.

Comment: Also, there is another issue with code. For example: if there is one entry in df44 for which Education_Period is 22.9 and Program_startDate  is 16/02/2019 and in df55 there are two entries with same Education_Period of 22.9 and Program_startDate  of 16/02/2019 then in output both are shown. But as I wrote in my question that If there are more than one records with similar ‘Education_Period’ and closest ‘Program_startDate’ then choose one at random.

Comment: If @Oskar_U or anyone else could please guide me to deal with above issues?

Comment: maybe `.nsmallest(1)` will do the trick... also I'd try to split joined dataset to subsets of 1) inner matches, 2) outer matches and process them separately